# ¿ Como añadir una vista antes de un navigation controller en un proyecto con storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

Tengo un proyecto que comienza con un `LaunchScreen` y seguidamente comienza el `Storyboard` con un `NavigationController` del que cuelgan las demás vistas.

Me interesaría agregar una nueva vista entre el `LaunchScreen` y el `Navigation Controller`.

¿Cómo lo debería hacer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Añade un nuevo ViewControllerScene  y marca la casilla "Is Initial View Controller" de ese nuevo ViewControllerScene en la casilla del inspector de atributos.

Después haz la llamada para presentar el Navigation controller

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NombreDeTuVCSiguiente") as NombreDeTuVCSiguiente 
 vc.newsObj = newsObj
 navigationController?.pushViewController(vc,
 animated: true)
```

También puedes hacerlo con un segue, pero sin  poner nada de código en la pregunta tampoco puedo seguir un patrón para darte una respuesta más específica.

Comment: Alfinal he agregago una nueva vista al storyboard, he marcado la casilla "Is Initial View Controller". En Title le he puesto un nombre a ese nuevo ViewControllerScene. Me falta agregar un segue a la vista del navigation controller. ¿ Como se haría ?

Comment: ¿ El archivo .h y .m de esa nueva vista inicial como lo agrego al proyecto automáticamente sin poner código ?

Comment: Lo que debes hacer es crear una nueva clase que extienda de UIViewController y después en el inspector del viewcontrollerscene indicarle que la clase sea la que has creado.

Comment: El problema que tengo es que la siguiente vista es un navigationController nombre de la clase en Custom Class me sale como UINavigationController y este navigationController luego apunta a una vista con nombre mainViewController. Como debo indicarlo en el prepareForSegue para que cuando entre un dato en un textField me salte al MainViewController. Si lo hago directamente con MainViewController *mainviewController = [segue destinationViewController] me aparece la vista MainViewController pero sin el navigationController

Comment: Echa un vistazo a esta respuesta: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28788442/6203030 debes instanciar el Navigation Controller que quieres mostrar, si el ViewController incluido en el Navigation Controller que quieres mostrar está referenciado ya desde el StoryBoard. </br> Si no, prueba a referenciar el segue desde tu ViewController de login a tu NavigationController en lugar de a tu ViewController nuevo.

Comment: Despues de mirarmelo he conseguido saltar a la siguiente vista con el navigationController implementando el siguiente código dentro del prepareForSegue. 'UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;MainViewController *mainViewController = (MainViewController*)navigationController.topViewController; mainViewController.pass = [self.txtPass text];' Pero ahora necesito implementar que si el código no es correcto vuelva a la vista de inicio.

Comment: Click sobre el segue y en los atributos le das un nombre. Después, revisa esta respuesta: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28883211/6203030 Donde debes implementar el método que indican para que sea llamado antes del prepareforSegue.